# Comparing two rows and highlighting unmatched contents

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, excel-2013

Using Microsoft Excel 2013 I have two rows I want to compare and highlight unmatched contents in both rows. I need comparison end to end. For example:

```
        A       B     C    D     E 
ROW1    11      22    33   44    55
ROW2    11      22    57   45    55
```

Expected result : Unmatched contents' cells `33`, `44`, `57`, `45` should be highlighted or those cells have some background color.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way may be to select A1:E1 and HOME > Styes - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to deteremine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**

```
=A1<>A2
```

with formatting of your choice, then select A2:E2 and repeat.

Comment: Thanks...It really helped a lot. Now I want to compare first three rows with next three rows and highlight the differences in both. Please help on same..Thanks in advance